# getting the fractional part of the significand and the sign bit of "the" javascript number NaN

Tags: javascript, floating-point, double

For a `NaN` value (e.g. the exponent is 11111111111) in javascript, is there any way of getting the sign bit and the significant value (ignoring the implicit 1 bit)?

And if this is not the case, does this imply that a `double (Number)` in javascript does not represent `2^64` possible states, rather (`2^64 - 2^52`) possible states?

Comment: You can do tricks with typed arrays to get at the bits of a number. Make a Float64 typed array with one element and put your number in it. Then use its buffer to make a UInt8 array that's 8 long, and now you can look at the bits via each of the 8 bytes.

Comment: Note that it's *possible* that `NaN` values are normalized to some particular value among all the possible `NaNs` available in the spec. (if I'm remembering the spec right; I could be confusing `NaNs` with denormals.)

Comment: You may wish to read [the standard itself regarding the definition of the number type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type), where it says, "In some implementations, external code might be able to detect a difference between various Not-a-Number values, but such behaviour is implementation-dependent; to ECMAScript code, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each other."

Comment: As to your second question, the answer is the same as it is for any other language based on IEEE floating point, and that answer is "yes".  Not all bit patterns are valid numbers.

Comment: @Pointy that is a fantastic idea, but isn't that inconsistent with what Heretic Monkey says?

Comment: @Nick I don't know for sure; the fact is that typed array buffers can be shared between views, so the bits are there one way or another.

Comment: @Pointy this is truly magnificent, I just wanted to store a 64 bit integer in a double, so this view works even better. I will test to see if the major browsers maintain the redundant bits in the double when its NaN

Comment: @Pointy: The question asks about states, not numbers. The IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary format has 64 bits, and 2^64 states of it are distinguishable. The IEEE-754 standard refers a “floating-point datum” as a thing which may be either a number (including infinities) or a NaN. There may be a “payload” in the bits in the significand of a NaN, so all 2^64 states are usable in good implementations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil right, thank you for posting the clarification. As you probably can sympathize, the precise details of the format aren't at the front of most programmers' minds on a day-to-day basis, and I certainly don't think about it much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Heretic Monkey pointed out, the specification specifically states that NaN numbers in javascript are all indistinguishable -

"In some implementations, external code might be able to detect a difference between various Not-a-Number values, but such behaviour is implementation-dependent; to ECMAScript code, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each other."

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type

So it looks like it is impossible - or at least not possible in a platform-independent manner.

One suggestion was to use typed arrays. This seems to work in IE and Chrome, but not in firefox! The problem is when you store the double in a variable, in firefox it will lose all the bit patterns you set for a NaN value...

```js
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var floats = new Float64Array(buffer);
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);

floats[0] = NaN;

var print_float_bytes = function() {
  var pstr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
    pstr = pstr + " " + bytes[i];
  }

  console.log(pstr);
};

console.log("printing a fresh NaN");
print_float_bytes();

bytes[7] = 255;
console.log("printing a NaN with the sign bit as 1");
print_float_bytes();

bytes[0] = 1;
console.log("printing a NaN with the significand as a number slightly bigger than 1 and a positive sign");
print_float_bytes();

console.log("printing the floating point number: " + floats[0]);

var p = floats[0];
floats[0] = p;

console.log("printing roundtripped NaN");
print_float_bytes();

var pointless = function(pdbl) {
  return pdbl;
};

p = floats[0];
p = pointless(p);

floats[0] = p;

console.log("printing even more roundtripped NaN");
print_float_bytes();
```

Comment: So the Firefox JavaScript engine does something like "canonicalize" the `NaN` values? That may make some other code easier, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah it does, also internet explorer has the sign bit as 1 by default. I'm not really sure why firefox canonicalizes the NaN values, I presumed it would be dependent on your machine (and it very well might be!).